# Android/iOS programming to trigger an action

Tags: android, ios, mobile-application

Is there any possibility to trigger an action on Android?
Like if we send a message to an android phone, it should execute some instruction, like running an app or something.

Is it possible with Android? Or iOS?

Or can the event be anything like reception of an email or phone call from a specific number or anything that can be done remotely?

Something as shown in the link [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/trigger-actions-on-your-android-device-automatically/). But I want to know how to program these triggers.
Can someone help me out, please?

I want to manipulate the network settings so that it can automatically switch on the Wi-Fi or data and send back some data. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can trigger an action on android.

For that, you need to use a broadcastreceiver (here is a good article about how to use it http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Here is a simple example of the source code in order to display a message to the user when a sms is received.

http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.ch/2010/10/receiving-sms-using-broadcastreceiver.html

Comment: can get android to switch on its data or use the network if an sms from some particular source is received?

Comment: Yes, from the broadcastreceiver, you can start a background service and then make network connection or anything else

Comment: any such thing available for the ios?

Comment: I don't know.. I never developed for an iOS platform.. 
iOS is more closed than Android so in my opinion it's more difficult but not impossible.